# Create a transaction from addresses A and B sending to address C

Tags: transactions, bitcore

Related: [Using bitcore to create a transaction with two addresses and change address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37609/using-bitcore-to-create-a-transaction-with-two-addresses-and-change-address)

I would like to create a transaction from addresses **A** and **B** sending to address **C**

In the above question I get a little confused (it looks like hes doing one transaction that sends from addresses **A** and **B** to addresses **C** and **D** receiving change at address **E**) because it looks like he is signing it with the two receiving addresses!

Usually when I create and sign a tx with [Bitcore](https://bitcore.io/api/lib/transaction) I sign it with the sending address's private key not the receiving address (in my case the receiving address would be a user I do not personally know)

The bitcore docs say:

> To send a transaction to a multisig address, the API is the same as <s>in the above example</s>. To spend outputs that require multiple signatures, the process needs extra information: the public keys of the signers that can unlock that output.

```
var multiSigTx = new Transaction()
.from(utxo, publicKeys, threshold)
.change(address)
.sign(myKeys);

var serialized = multiSigTx.toObject();
```

The two parts to this that confuse me are:

- Bitcore quote - To send a transaction to a multisig address...

Is this different from a regular address? I notice that the example is lacking `.to(address, amount)`

- Why is Richard from the related question signing with the receiving address's private keys?

---

Logically shouldn't my desired action look something like this?:

```
var transaction=new Bitcore.Transaction()
.fee(fee)
.from([output_A,output_B])
.to(pubkey_C,satoshis-fee)
.change(address_A)                    //don't loose the change
.sign([privatekey_A,privatekey_B]);
```

*output_A is from address A and output_B is from address B (both my addresses)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in how your transaction should look like. However, you are getting confused since you are looking for the wrong concept.

You are not sending funds to a multisig address, that is an address shared by multiple users in which some of them need to sign a transaction or order to spend funds from the address. You are (if I've got it right) willing to spend funds from two different addresses (`A` and `B`) in order to send funds to a third address: `C`.

Therefore, what you should build is a transaction with inputs from both addresses `A` and `B`, in which each input may be sign by the corresponding address from the latter two.

Comment: In my example the `.from` function takes two inputs. I wrote output_A,output_B as the inputs because I was thinking of them being the outputs of the previous transaction... we are both correct; thank you!